Unable to correctly define macro for tikz nodes
I need to write several such commands:
\node[state](n0){$n_0$};\node[]at([shift={(.35,.45)}]n0){1};

So, the overall document could look as:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[state](n0){$n_0$};\node[]at([shift={(.35,.45)}]n0){1};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}

I would like to define a macro to write it more compactly as:
\newcommand{\ndLDblC}[5]{(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4,#5)}]#1){#3};}

Thereafter, the original command should be written as:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\newcommand{\ndLDblC}[5]{(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4,#5)}]#1){#3};}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] \ndLDblC{n0}{$n_0$}{1}{.35}{.45}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}

or
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\def\ndLDblC#1#2#3#4#5{(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4,#5)}]#1){#3};}
\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[state] \ndLDblC{n0}{$n_0$}{1}{.35}{.45}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}

However, this doesn't work. Tikz thinks I haven't supplied the requisite label.
How can the macro be written correctly?
I'm not putting the whole of it in a single macro because I have to add positioning to other similar node drawing commands.
I though I would need to use \expandafter, but I don't know the proper usage, especially in the tikz context. An example to that effect would be useful.

you would need to expand your macro before the parser reaches it. so you would need \ExpandArgs or \expandafters etc. this will make your code far more complicated and far less clear. in general, this is the wrong approach for tikz, imho. you could define a single macro to create both nodes, but are you really going to remember which argument goes where? instead, use what tikz gives you. depending on the details, you probably want to look at (1) key-values for the things which vary, (2) \foreach loops to iterate over cases, (3) pics (probably not but unclear) and/or code keys/handlers.

please post code for a complete minimal example we can compile. that way people can understand what you're trying to achieve with this method and suggest more productive strategies.

please do note I am not recommending putting it in a single macro. I'm saying that a macro is the wrong way to go here. also, you need either to load tikz as a package or give the argument to standalone. and your class line uses incorrect syntax.

The first example (without macros) doesn't compile. Please, show a complete compilable one.

Sorry about the faulty code. The first example compiles. The later one don't.

The macro is just meant to expand to (for example) (n0){$n_0$};\node[]at([shift={(.35,.45)}]n0){1}; taking the following parameters: {n0}{$n_0$}{1}{.35}{.45}

you can't write the macro so the syntax you want will work i.e. so you can say \node \mymacro{}{}{}{}{}. the macro is not the issue here. it is what you are trying to do with it. for it to work, \mymacro has to get expanded before \node and the only way to do that is to put something before \node. so for each case, you'll need something like <expansion instructions> \node \mymacro{}{}{}{}{}. even then, any solution will be rather specific, so you won't have something flexible to work with. once pgf sees \node, it has to see the right stuff after - especially the ;.

Thanks for the explanation, at least I know what's going wrong!

A single macro served the purpose:
\newcommand{\ndLDbl}[6]{\node[#5]#6(#1){#2};\node[]at([shift={(#4)}]#1){#3};}

